# Наследование string.

Tags: ооп, c++

Хочу добавить string мой метод find_next. Пытаюсь наследовать:

```
class advstring:public string{
public:
string find_next(string str);
  static int i;
  advstring.find // выдаёт ошибку (advstring не содержит find)
};
```

Как отнаследовать так, чтобы в advstring были все методы string?

Comment: Для "отнаследовать так, чтобы в advstring были все методы string" ничего особенного делать не надо - все само собой получится. Но у вас написана синтаксическая каша. Сначала исправляйте ее, а уж потом будете беспокоиться о наследовании.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) код, который Вы привели - неверный. Неверный синтаксически. то есть, метод find_next должен выглядеть как минимум где то так

```
string find_next(string str);
  static int i;
  advstring.find(/*здесь параметры*/);
  return /*что то возвратить*/;
};
```

2) `static int i;`  - это поле будет общее для всех экземпляров данного класса. Поэтому поиск может давать самые интересные результаты.

3) наследоваться от std::string не стоит. У него деструктор невиртуальный. А это грозит утечками памяти.

В данном случае лучше не наследоваться, а делегировать. То есть, создать класс, у которого есть приватное поле типа `std::string` и выносим отдельно все нужные методы.

Но если хочется делать правильно, то следует сделать не метод+наследование, а отдельный алгоритм - то есть функцию или даже класс.

Comment: "А это грозит утечками памяти." Это грозит неопределенным поведением. Зачем снова упоминать этот расхожий миф про некие "утечки памяти" - совершенно не ясно.

Answer (score 2):

От себя добавлю уже сказанное - класс *std::string* изначально не разрабатывался, как базовый. В нем нет виртуальных функций, как и нет виртуального деструктора. С точки зрения законов ООП, наследоваться от него запрещено, но при большом желании можно - компилятор ничего не скажет вам, но обязательно будут проблемы.

Вариант расширить его функционал - создать класс с композицией (включающий член данных) *std::string*

```
class advstring {
public:
  std::string find_next(const std::string& str);
private:
  std::string m_str;
}
```

Проблема такой реализации в том, что хочешь не хочешь в классе *advstring* придется продублировать в секции *public* весь открытый функционал *std::string* и прокинуть мосты через член класса *m_str*

Проще релизовать свободную функцию если в ее теле не требуется обращения к закрытым членам базового класса *std::string*

```
std::string find_next(const std::string& str);
```

Comment: "...но обязательно будут проблемы". Проблемы тут могут быть только в одном случае - при попытке полиморфного динамического удаления, т.е. `delete` объекта-наследника через указатель типа `std::string *`. Если не делается попыток полиморфного `delete`, то и никаких проблем не будет. Поэтому ни о каком "обязательно" речи быть не может.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Это я, конечно, перегнул палку на счет обязательно будут..

Comment: Сегодня не делают попыток, а завтра кто то может и сделать.

Comment: @KoVadim: Завтра кто-то может и на ноль разделить. Но это не повод запрещать операцию деления или даже избегать ее.